# react library that this site using

Tags: reactjs

I'm make a graphical website, so I use three.js for implement it.

For a reference, I searched a lots of site and found some interest site.

`https://www.magicleap.com/` is made with React.js.

Connect the site and scroll up/down, it's effect like move forward and backward.

So I wonder that, which library used in this site to implement animation with scroll?

Anyone who know about that, please comment it.

Thanks.

Comment: It's a question we all have. They have one the most impressive websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they are using [next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/).

Sources:

- https://react-etc.net/entry/who-is-using-next-js
- https://builtwith.com/?https%3a%2f%2fwww.magicleap.com%2f

Comment: Next is used for SSR, it doesn't do the scrolling effect